# adding table to wpf application MVS 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

As I saw the wpf doesn't sopplie DataGridView .. Then have any other option ? 
I need to creat table to show Data base .
I try to do DataTable but with no succses.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wpf Has DataGrids (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and ListViews (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `ListView` along with a `DataGridView`:

[listview-with-gridview](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/)

Although you are right, there is no standalone `DataGridView`.